# How to edit borders and separators in GNOME shell theme?

Tags: css, gtk3, theming, gnome-shell

I'm making a GNOME (3.16) shell theme and already made the necessary changes. However, the separators in the popup menu (a.k.a. aggregate menu) are still in the same color. I can't find the code in `gnome-shell.css` to change the size and color of the separators. I also can't find the code the remove the circles around the settings and shutdown button. Does anyone know what the classes are called?

I'm searching the following lines:

- separators in popup/aggregate menu (also the one when the menu is activated)
- circles around the buttons (system settings, shutdown)
- the color of the date in the agenda menu
- the hover color of a date in the agenda menu

Comment: For GTK applications you can use the Inspector (Shift+Ctrl+D) to find out these things, but unfortunately I don't think such a thing exists for Gnome Shell... The only suggestion I can give you is to look at the Gnome Shell source code.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, the shortcut doesn't work in GNOME shell. I dug in the source code and found out the must by now. Although it's still a little strange that there isn't an easy to find tutorial/guide on how to theme the shell.

Comment: I'm glad you found out how to do it. Now that you know, why not start a section on the Gnome wiki documenting what you've found out? [Here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Theming) might be a nice place to put it.